# SQL Server - using variable in triggers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a trigger set on a table to run after Insert and I want to query the incoming data with that already in the target table, then append a different message based on the changes identified.

Here's what I have so far

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_Measure_Insert_Audit] 
   ON [dbo].[Measures_slave]
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @message    VARCHAR(MAX)

        insert into aud_Measures
        (
        measure_FK,
        [description],
        oldname,
        [newname],
        milestone
        )
select
        i.measure_PK,
        CASE
            WHEN (SELECT TOP 1 measure_name FROM Measures_slave s WHERE s.slave_PK = i.slave_PK -1) <> i.measure_name THEN 'Measure Name Changed to <b> ' + i.measure_name + ' </b>'
        END,
        (SELECT TOP 1 measure_name FROM Measures_slave s WHERE s.slave_PK = i.slave_PK -1),
        i.measure_name,
        --'Test Audit Entry',
        'Yes'

  from
        inserted i

END
```

I want to replace the CASE WHEN with a list of either IFs or WHENs that go down each field on both measure_slave and Inserted and append a message to @message if a difference is found.

I'm trying to achieve this, essentially:

```
select
        i.measure_PK,
        CASE
            --WHEN (SELECT TOP 1 measure_name FROM Measures_slave s WHERE s.slave_PK = i.slave_PK -1) <> i.measure_name THEN 'Measure Name Changed to <b> ' + i.measure_name + ' </b>'
            WHEN (SELECT TOP 1 measure_name FROM Measures_slave s WHERE s.slave_PK = i.slave_PK -1) <> i.measure_name SET @message = 'Measure Name Changed to <b> ' + i.measure_name + ' </b>'
            WHEN (SELECT TOP 1 calculation_steps FROM Measures_slave s WHERE s.slave_PK = i.slave_PK -1) <> i.calculation_steps SET @message = @message + 'Steps changed to:  <b> ' + i.calculation_steps + ' </b>'
        END,
        (SELECT TOP 1 measure_name FROM Measures_slave s WHERE s.slave_PK = i.slave_PK -1),
        i.measure_name,
        --'Test Audit Entry',
        'Yes'

  from
        inserted i
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for, can you elaborate on exactly what it is you need help with? i.e. What's stopping you for doing this yourself ?

Comment: So the measure_slave table has various fields that could be changed by a user and this trigger records an entry for those changes, however I want to output a message depending on which were changed. At the moment I've hard-typed the change in there but I cannot get the trigger to accept CASE WHEN xx SET @message = 'Message'

Comment: I've updated the question to illustrate what I'm trying to get to...

Comment: so what's wrong with your trigger query ?

Comment: why is there `-1` after each `i.slave_PK` in the where clause of your subqueries ?

Comment: @squirrel: various error messages... "multi-part identifier i.measure_PK could not be found", "multi-part identifier i.slave_PK could not be found", incorrect text near ','...

Comment: @GuidoG: because I want it to reference the most recent entry from the table. I did have it without but it was referencing the incoming value rather than what was already there

Comment: I dont understand how -1 can help you there. This makes no sense

Comment: anyway, in a case statement you cannot execute other statements, you only can feed values there. `case when 1 = 1 then set @a = 'test'...`is invalid. You cannot do `set`in a case statement or any other code

Comment: The `slave_PK` field is an identity being auto-incremented, so I'd assume it's already been incremented by 1 when this runs, so I need the -1 to get the value of the most recent.

Comment: The -1 will either return no result, or the complete wrong record. I would not do that. This will only produce very strange errors you will be debugging for hours later

Comment: @GuidoG - it seems to work. I've run it on it's own and brings back the value I need. As I say, without it, it didn't fire off because the 2 values matched. So will a list of `IF`s work?

Comment: A list if `if's` also wont help you, because you are still in the `SELECT` clause of your query where you also cannot execute a `SET`statement or any other statement

Comment: OK, so where's best to do it then?

Comment: ìt seems to work`is what caused many many debugging hours in many projects. If you dont get the correct records without the `-1`then someting else is wrong with your query, find that

Comment: select @variable = (select TOP 1 ... ) from ...

Comment: OK I will look into that but I still need to solve the issue of setting the variable in a loop to identify changes to each field...

Comment: The only way to set a variable in a SELECT is like this `select @variable = (select top 1 etc) from etc...`

Comment: But that wont work in a trigger like this because the inserted table can have more than one row. If you really want to work with variables you need to make a cursor, which is very very slow and should be avoided in triggers.

Comment: Right, so what I want to do is not possible, or should be avoided?

Comment: what is it exact you want to do ? Inserting records in an audit table ? Yes that can be done with triggers, just make your query without needing variables.

Comment: I already have that sorted. I want to include a message in a field dependent on the changes the trigger has found. So if 1 change was found then make the variable be Message 1. If two were found then make it Messages 1 and 3, for example.

Comment: you will have to do that in your query. It might become large and complex but I think its the only way. Also always check the performance of queries in triggers (not only now but also later at regular times) because they can make inserting/updating/deleting slow sometimes

Comment: to get more answers you need to edit your question and add sample data and expected result in your audit table. Then we can help much better

Comment: Could you describe the structure of the table being updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be able to achive what you need without using a variable:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_Measure_Insert_Audit] 
   ON [dbo].[Measures_slave]
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO aud_Measures
            (
            measure_FK,
            [description],
            oldname,
            [newname],
            milestone
            )

    SELECT  
            i.measure_PK,
            CASE WHEN (i.measure_name <> s.measure_name) THEN 'Measure Name Changed to <b> ' + i.measure_name + ' </b>' ELSE '' END +             -- The resulting value from this line concatenates with 
            CASE WHEN (i.calculation_steps  <> s.calculation_steps ) THEN 'Steps changed to:  <b> ' + i.calculation_steps + ' </b>' ELSE '' END,  -- the resulting value from of this line
            s.measure_name,
            i.measure_name 
            'Yes' 
    FROM Inserted i LEFT JOIN Measures_slave s ON s.slave_PK = i.slave_PK -1
    -- If you want to audit only the rows that in which there IS actually a difference in any of measure_name  or calculation_steps columns, then use the following:
    WHERE (i.measure_name <> s.measure_name) OR (i.calculation_steps  <> s.calculation_steps )
END
```

Comment: Emilio perfect! This absolutely works exactly how I need it to. So simple but I was clearly making it more complicated in my head. Thank you

Comment: That's great. Glad I could help.